# Remove item from Observable Collection in Nested Foreach

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, foreach

I have these nested Foreach :

```
foreach (var item1 in ocChoicesinItem)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in temp.ItemsInInvoiceChoices)
            {
                if (item1.ChoicesId == item2.ChoicesId)
                    ocChoicesinItem.Remove(item1);
            }
        }
```

The problem occur when remove item from ocChoicesinItem, gives me this error:

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add 'ToList' statements if you want to remove items in the collection :

```
foreach (var item1 in ocChoicesinItem.ToList())
    {
        foreach (var item2 in temp.ItemsInInvoiceChoices)
        {
            if (item1.ChoicesId == item2.ChoicesId)
                ocChoicesinItem.Remove(item1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a collection while iterating that collection, as you are making your `Enumerator` invalid when calling `MoveNext`

Try:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   public static int RemoveAll<T>(
      this ObservableCollection<T> coll, Func<T, bool> condition)
 {
      var itemsToRemove = coll.Where(condition).ToList();

      foreach (var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
      {
          coll.Remove(itemToRemove);
      }

      return itemsToRemove.Count;
 }
}  

ocChoicesinItem.RemoveAll(x => temp.ItemsInInvoiceChoices.Any(y => y.ChoicesId == x.ChoicesId);
```

Comment: There's just Remove or RemoveAt, There is no RemoveAll ??

Comment: I added an extension method just for that.

Comment: Or... you can just use Seb's answer.  Convert `Enumerable` to a list during iteration.

Comment: Whichever suits him best

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
List<string> ocChoicesinItem = new List<string>{"One", "Two", "Three"};
List<string> ItemsInInvoiceChoices = new List<string> { "Three" };

ocChoicesinItem.RemoveAll(x => ItemsInInvoiceChoices.Contains(x));
```

Obviously I am using strings as I don't know what type your collections contain; you may have to compare the ID's in the predicate.

Comment: There's just Remove or RemoveAt, There is no RemoveAll ??

Comment: @AbdusalamElsherif Yes there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jay , nope, there's mo `RemoveAll` method in `ObserveableCollection`